# Update webpage when certain DIV content updates on server

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, webapp2

I have a dynamic webpage which displays a list of user messages. However, when a user adds a message, the webpage must be refreshed to view the change. I am wondering if there is anyway to update only the one div with class name "container" whenever there is a "message posted" (change to source). I want this to be done without an actual refresh, as that would be pretty obtrusive, I just want the one div class to update. I appreciate any answers, I am a complete newbie to JS...

Comment: it could work `if(document.getElementsByClassName("container").length) location.reload();`

Comment: @JuanCaicedo nah, that just puts the page into a refresh loop

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out sockets and socket.io for real time messaging stuff. My suggestion is that keep on reading and trying out code.

Comment: this is more of a learning experience for me, not a production site. Just want to figure this out.